# node.js не работает запуск из командной строки

Tags: node.js

Только начал осваивать Node.js. В командной строке пишу node, запускается консоль node.js. Если скопипастить код js скрипта туда, он запускается. Допустим, в скрипте написано создание http сервера, он действительно создаётся, браузер открывает страницу, которую отдал сервер.

Теперь идём далее. Открываем опять обычную командную строку. В Windows файлы *.js ассоциированы, например, с блокнотом (notepad). В командной строке перехожу в директорию с нужным скриптом (команда cd). Пишу node <имяскрипта>.js. По идее, node.js должен запустить этот скрипт. Что происходит - открывается notepad с исходником скрипта.

Где что нужно исправить?

Comment: а если проассоциировать файлы js с node?

Answer (score 3):

1. [Скринкаст NODE.JS](https://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/nodejs)
2. [Node.JS для решения задач](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-nodejs)
3. [Node.js для начинающих](http://www.nodebeginner.ru/)

В следующий раз попробуйте спросить [поисковик](https://yandex.ru/search/?lr=4&msid=1469303765.53555.22909.10500&text=node%20js%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) (ещё [тык](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=node%20js%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)) - он то же может давать правильные ответы!

***Дополнение ответа:***

> <sub>Цитата «[Node.JS для решения задач](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-nodejs)» [javascript.ru](http://javascript.ru/):</sub>
>
> **1. Установка**
>
> Для настройки окружения будет достаточно сделать два шага:
>
> Сначала установите сам сервер Node.JS.
>
> Если у вас Unix-система – рекомендуется собрать последнюю версию из исходников, а также NPM. Вы справитесь.
>
> Если Windows – посетите сайт http://nodejs.org или скачайте установщик (32 или 64-битный) с расширением .msi из http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/.
>
> Выберите директорию, в которой будете решать задачи. Запустите в ней:
>
> ```
> npm install node-static
> ```
>
> Это установит в текущую директорию модуль node-static, который станет автоматически доступным для скриптов из поддиректорий.
>
> **2. Проверка**
>
> Проверьте инсталяцию. Для этого:
>
> Создайте какую-нибудь поддиректорию и в ней файл server.js с таким содержимым:
>
> ```
> var http = require('http');
> var static = require('node-static');
> var file = new static.Server('.');
>
> http.createServer(function(req, res) {
>   file.serve(req, res);
> }).listen(8080);
>
> console.log('Server running on port 8080');
> ```
>
> Запустите его:
>
> ```
> node server.js.
> ```
>
> Должно вывести:
>
> ```
> Server running on port 8080
> ```
>
> Нельзя запустить больше одного сервера одновременно!
>   При попытке запуска двух серверов (например, в разных консолях) – будет конфликт портов и ошибка.
>
> Откройте в браузере http://127.0.0.1:8080/server.js.
>
> Должно вывести код файла server.js.
>
> Если всё работает – отлично, теперь вы готовы решать задачи.

Comment: Может инфу со ссылок вынести в ответ? Хотя бы основное?

Comment: Дополнил, основной информацией по началу работы с Node.js

Comment: в итоге поставил себе  NodeJS tools  для  Visual Studio. Там, по крайней мере, IDE  и дебаггер есть

Comment: Инструменты Node.js для Visual Studio: https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/features/node-js-vs.aspx